# how to specify second click in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a vertical menu bars in jquery, which open some submenu

```
<li><a>open</a>
<ul class='count'>
            <li><a>Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a>Sub-Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a>Sub-Menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

what i want when i click on open first time it will open the submenu, post that every time it will refresh the page.

i know    location.reload() used to reload the body but how to specify this events occurs from second click on the element not from the first click.

Comment: How about adding another clickHandler on first click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("selector").click(function() {
var $this = $(this);
if ($this.hasClass("clicked-once")) {
    // already been clicked once, refresh the page
    location.reload();
}
else {
    // first time this is clicked, mark it
    $this.addClass("clicked-once");
}
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JBv56/)**

Comment: i need to refresh the page from second click

Comment: Updated the answer.please check.

Comment: @Manish:it will check the fiddle added

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#menu li').one('click', function () {
    $(this).find('ul').show();
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        window.location.reload()
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nA4wH/)

The [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method is used to register an event handler which will get called only once, once the handler is called it is removed from the listener list.

Comment: An explanation on the use of [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) is probably useful to OP.

Comment: all the li is also effecting

Comment: @AtalShrivastava you need to tweak the `li` selector may be `$('#menu li:has(ul.count)').one('click'`

Comment: if you click on first li after opening the link it will aslo refresh the page Arun P Johny

Comment: @AtalShrivastava that is the requirement of that is what is happening... the fiddle seems to be fine

Answer (score 0):

Give a an id like this:

```
<a id="openLink">open</a>
```

Then add a eventListener:

```
$('#openLink').on('click', function(){
    $('#openLink').unbind('click');
    $('#openLink').on('click', function(){
          location.reload();
     });
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V48NZ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
var clicks = 0;
$('a').click(function(){
    if(clicks == 0){
        // first click
    }else{
        // second clik
    }
    ++clicks;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count=0;
    $("#menu").click(function(){
        if(count>=1)
        {
            //do something here
        }
        else
        {
            $("#menu>list.count").show();
        }
        count++;
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh sorry! i think after page refresh the count becomes zero, right?
Ok...How about cookies?